# Is socket.io data emitted from server protected?

Tags: node.js, express, authentication, socket.io

So I'm just learning socket.io and I think I know just enough to be dangerous. I've built a test (Node/Express) application that first takes you to a login page, then redirects you to an account page, after authenticating. The account page view is on a protected route, and it listens for a particular event emitted from the server and then displays that data in the browser. My question is if the data is being emitted from the server, can't it be listened for outside of the protected `/account` route and then viewed if someone knows the name of the event? If so, rendering the account view on a protected route is useless and I need to figure out how to authenticate a user before allowing the server to emit the data...right?

To clarify, my setup is as follows:

From server.js -

```
io.on('connection', (socket) => {
  console.log('New user connected...');
  socket.emit('data', {
    //data emitted
  });
});
```

From account.js (one of the js source scripts for my account.hbs view) -

```
socket.on('data', function (data) {
  //do some stuff with the data
});
```

Comment: websockets run over the http/https protocol. So if you secure your server over HTTPS or some TCP security method, your sockets will use the same protocols

Answer (score 0, accepted):

You haven't really disclosed enough for us to offer you info on your exact scenario so I'll generally describe how this works and what you do and don't need to worry about.

1. If you run your socket.io connection using TLS, then all data is protected in transit and cannot be snooped on by a middleman attack.  If your socket.io connection is not TLS, then data is visible to network snoopers.
2. It is not enough to protect only the `/account` route form which a socket.io connection is made.  You also have to protect the socket.io connection itself.  Otherwise, any code jockey can write up a script that will make a socket.io connection to your server and you will happily let it connect and send it data.  You need authentication on the socket.io connection itself.  socket.io offers middleware support for that and if you already have an authenticated session for the `/account` page, then you can implement middleware that requires that authenticated session before allowing the socket.io connection.  Then, you will have auth support for socket.io connections.

> My question is if the data is being emitted from the server, can't it be listened for outside of the protected /account route and then viewed if someone knows the name of the event?

If your socket.io connection is not running an encrypted channel such as TLS, then it can be snooped on.  Someone doesn't have to know the name of the event (it can be seen other ways) and it would be relatively easy to figure out the message name by just looking at the client JS in your web page.

> If so, rendering the account view on a protected route is useless and I need to figure out how to authenticate a user before allowing the server to emit the data...right?

I wouldn't say useless, but it's not sufficient to provide protection for the socket.io connection.  That connection needs it's own auth implementation which can likely piggyback on the same auth you did for the `/account` page.

---

**Summary:** Run socket.io on TLS (support https on your server and use an `https://xxxx` URL to connect for socket.io) and then implement authentication for your socket.io connections.

Comment: Awesome info, thanks! I'm authenticating with passport (using local strategy), so I guess I'll have to figure out how to ensure that the user is authenticated before allowing a connection to the socket.

Comment: For anyone else, I ended up installing the passport.socketio package from NPM and it was actually quite easy to use my authenticated session to protect my socket. Thanks again for the answer.